# Adding rows with duplicate indexes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a set of "unidirectional" airline data, somewhat like below (numbers are not sequential or the same for every row in actual data):

```
origin dest    a  b  c  d  e  f
BOS    JFK     1  2  3  4  5  6
       DCA     1  2  3  4  5  6
JFK    BOS     1  2  3  4  5  6
       DCA     1  2  3  4  5  6
DCA    BOS     1  2  3  4  5  6
       JFK     1  2  3  4  5  6
```

I want to get the "multidirectional" data, i.e. something like below:

```
air1 air2    a  b  c  d  e  f
BOS  JFK     2  4  6  8  10 12
     DCA     2  4  6  8  10 12
JFK  DCA     2  4  6  8  10 12
```

I've been experimenting with pivot tables but so far haven't found any remotely useful solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort your `origin` and `dest` columns by row firstly and then do a `groupby`, `sum` since it looks like that your result doesn't care about the order of the `origin` and `dest`:

```
import pandas as pd

df.reset_index(["origin", "dest"])
od = df.loc[:,'origin':'dest'].as_matrix()
od.sort()
df[['air1','air2']] = pd.DataFrame(od)
df.groupby(['air1','air2']).sum()

            a   b   c   d   e   f
air1 air2                       
BOS  DCA    2   4   6   8   10  12
     JFK    2   4   6   8   10  12
DCA  JFK    2   4   6   8   10  12
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to do. Pretty much worked, had to modify stuff a bit because one of the variables was acting weirdly when added (converted it to a string so it wouldn't add and it seems to work fine now).

Answer (score 1):

is that what you want?

```
In [133]: df.groupby('dest').sum().reset_index()
Out[133]:
  dest  a  b  c  d   e   f
0  BOS  2  4  6  8  10  12
1  DCA  2  4  6  8  10  12
2  JFK  2  4  6  8  10  12
```